# Black screen no mouse no way to access safe mode or anything else (windows 10)

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot

So i've recently upgraded to windows 10, and since upgrading, my computer has given me a black screen without a cursor or anything else. Fortunately, a few times it tried to auto repair, and kicked me into the troubleshoot menu. I rebooted in safe mode to the exact same error, no cursor or anything. After about 10 more restarts the auto repair kicked me into the troubleshoot and i tried to reset my PC, but it got stuck at 95% and went black, with the computer turning itself off. I thought it was restarting. After about 2 hours of nothing, i restarted the computer myself, to get straight into my old black screen, no cursor, only this time despite rebooting about 30-50 times, still no auto-repair. Also i have been searching the web for answers, and while there are many cases like mine, none of them work for me. Please help, i want my windows computer back, this mac is bad!

Answer (score 1):

Do you by chance have a repair disc for your previous Windows? Or do you have one for Windows 10?

If you get the loading wheel for Windows 10 you can hard power the computer off three times and it should go to the preparing automatic repair and then into the troubleshooting section. Once you get into the troubleshooting section I would suggest going to advanced options and then go back to a previous build if you can. That should bring you back to whatever you had before the 10 upgrade.

I've also found if you can get the Windows 10 upgrade on a flash drive and upgrade from that it has the likelihood to fail far less if you still want Windows 10.

Comment: no repair disc, i had a backup but it didn't show up on the restore screen. Also the going back to a previous build ended up with the computer saying restarting for about an hour before i restarted it manually.

Comment: If you can get into command prompt from advanced options by powering off the computer 2 or 3 times while you see the loading wheel you could try running BCDBOOT C:\Windows /L en-us /V

Comment: it worked, i managed to reset my computer, it now works.

Comment: Did you end up using BCDBOOT or was it something else?

Comment: well i went into advanced options and reset everything. When i booted up the computer it worked, and i got to reinstalling everything. However the next time i tried to boot it up, after turning it off and going to bed, the computer gave me the same old black screen no mouse problem. That leads me to believe that my computer isn't compatible with windows 10, so i'm going to reset it back once i reset it again.